# Listar conteúdo de uma lista com um método

Tags: c#, lista

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    class Candidato
    {
        public int numeroPartido {get;set;}
        public string nomeCandidato {get;set;}
        public int quantidadeVotos {get;set;}
    }
    class Eleitor
    {
        public string CPF {get;set;}
        public string nomeEleitor {get;set;}
        public Boolean votoRealizado {get;set;}
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var z = 0;
        var contador = 0;
        var opcao = 0;

        List<Candidato> listaCandidatos = new List<Candidato>();
        listaCandidatos.Add(new Candidato {numeroPartido = 17, nomeCandidato = "Fulano", quantidadeVotos = 0});
        listaCandidatos.Add(new Candidato {numeroPartido = 13, nomeCandidato = "Ciclano", quantidadeVotos = 0});
        listaCandidatos.Add(new Candidato {numeroPartido = 45, nomeCandidato = "Deltrano", quantidadeVotos = 0});
        listaCandidatos.Add(new Candidato {numeroPartido = 99, nomeCandidato = "Branco", quantidadeVotos = 0});
        listaCandidatos.Add(new Candidato {numeroPartido = 999, nomeCandidato = "Nulo", quantidadeVotos = 0});

        List<Eleitor> listaEleitores = new List<Eleitor>();
        listaEleitores.Add(new Eleitor {CPF = "1", nomeEleitor = "João", votoRealizado = false});
        listaEleitores.Add(new Eleitor {CPF = "2", nomeEleitor = "Maria", votoRealizado = false});
        listaEleitores.Add(new Eleitor {CPF = "3", nomeEleitor = "Antonio", votoRealizado = false});
        listaEleitores.Add(new Eleitor {CPF = "4", nomeEleitor = "Marcos", votoRealizado = false});
        listaEleitores.Add(new Eleitor {CPF = "5", nomeEleitor = "Ana", votoRealizado = false});
        listaEleitores.Add(new Eleitor {CPF = "6", nomeEleitor = "Marcia", votoRealizado = false});
        listaEleitores.Add(new Eleitor {CPF = "7", nomeEleitor = "Marcio", votoRealizado = false});
        listaEleitores.Add(new Eleitor {CPF = "8", nomeEleitor = "Carla", votoRealizado = false});
        listaEleitores.Add(new Eleitor {CPF = "9", nomeEleitor = "Bruna", votoRealizado = false});
        listaEleitores.Add(new Eleitor {CPF = "10", nomeEleitor = "Mara", votoRealizado = false});

        while (opcao == 1 || opcao == 2 || contador < 10){
            Console.WriteLine("DIGITE A OPÇÃO DESEJADA:");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - PARA VOTAR.");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - LISTAR VOTAÇÃO.");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
            opcao = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (opcao == 1){
                Console.Write("DIGITE SEU CPF PARA REALIZAR O VOTO: ");
                var CPFEleitor = Console.ReadLine();
                foreach (var itemEleitores in listaEleitores)
                {
                    if (itemEleitores.CPF.Equals(CPFEleitor) && itemEleitores.votoRealizado == true){
                        Console.WriteLine("ELEITOR: "+itemEleitores.nomeEleitor);
                        y = 1;
                    }
                    if (itemEleitores.CPF.Equals(CPFEleitor) && itemEleitores.votoRealizado == false){
                        Console.WriteLine("ELEITOR: "+itemEleitores.nomeEleitor.ToUpper());
                        contador++;
                        itemEleitores.votoRealizado = true;
                        Console.Write("DIGITE O NUMERO DO SEU CANDIDATO: ");        
                        var numeroCandidato = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (!numeroCandidato.ToString().Equals("")){
                            foreach (var itemCandidados in listaCandidatos)
                            {
                                if (itemCandidados.numeroPartido.ToString().Equals(numeroCandidato)){
                                    Console.WriteLine("CANDIDATO: "+itemCandidados.nomeCandidato.ToUpper());
                                    Console.WriteLine("VOTAÇÃO CONCLUÍDA.");
                                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                                    itemCandidados.quantidadeVotos = itemCandidados.quantidadeVotos + 1;
                                    z = 1;
                                }
                            }
                            if (z == 0){
                                foreach (var itemCandidados in listaCandidatos)
                                {
                                    if (itemCandidados.numeroPartido == 999){
                                        itemCandidados.quantidadeVotos = itemCandidados.quantidadeVotos + 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            x = 1;
                        } else {
                            foreach (var itemCandidados in listaCandidatos)
                            {
                                if (itemCandidados.numeroPartido == 99){
                                    itemCandidados.quantidadeVotos = itemCandidados.quantidadeVotos + 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (x == 0 && y == 0){
                    Console.WriteLine("CPF NÃO CADASTRADO");
                }
                if (y == 1){
                    Console.WriteLine("ELEITOR JÁ REALIZOU SEU VOTO");
                }
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
                z = 0;
            } else if (opcao == 2){
                foreach (var item in listaCandidatos)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Candidato {0} ({1}). Votos {2}.", item.nomeCandidato, item.numeroPartido, item.quantidadeVotos);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("OPÇÃO INVÁLIDA. TENTE NOVAMENTE.");
            }
            opcao = 0;
        }
        if (contador == 10){
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("VOTAÇÃO ENCERRADA. TODOS OS ELEITORES JÁ VOTARAM.");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
            foreach (var item in listaCandidatos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Candidato {0} ({1}). Votos {2}.", item.nomeCandidato, item.numeroPartido, item.quantidadeVotos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gostaria de criar um método para listar o conteúdo de uma dessas minhas listas, como já faço aqui:

```
Console.WriteLine("VOTAÇÃO ENCERRADA. TODOS OS ELEITORES JÁ VOTARAM.");
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
foreach (var item in listaCandidatos)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Candidato {0} ({1}). Votos {2}.", item.nomeCandidato, item.numeroPartido, item.quantidadeVotos);
}
```

Porém não estou conseguindo passar essa minha lista como parâmetro para meu método para assim percorrer ela e exibir seu conteúdo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provavelmente você não está conseguindo passar como parâmetro por causa que a classe não é publica.

Alterei seu código para a seguinte forma:

<sub>Ajustei também os nomes das propriedades, em C# utilizamos [Pascal Case](http://fabiocabral.gabx.com.br/2013/09/entenda-o-que-e-pascal-case-e-camel-case.html) e a classe `Boolean` tem um "apelido", `bool` que é mais fácil e curto de digitar ;)</sub>

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public class Candidato
    {
        public int NumeroPartido { get; set; }
        public string NomeCandidato { get; set; }
        public int QuantidadeVotos { get; set; }
    }
    public class Eleitor
    {
        public string Cpf { get; set; }
        public string NomeEleitor { get; set; }
        public bool VotoRealizado { get; set; }
    }

    public static void ExibeResultado(List<Candidato> listaCandidatos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("VOTAÇÃO ENCERRADA. TODOS OS ELEITORES JÁ VOTARAM.");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
        foreach (var item in listaCandidatos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Candidato {0} ({1}). Votos {2}.", item.NomeCandidato, item.NumeroPartido, item.QuantidadeVotos);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var z = 0;
        var contador = 0;
        var opcao = 0;

        List<Candidato> listaCandidatos = new List<Candidato>
        {
            new Candidato { NumeroPartido = 17, NomeCandidato = "Fulano", QuantidadeVotos = 0 },
            new Candidato { NumeroPartido = 13, NomeCandidato = "Ciclano", QuantidadeVotos = 0 },
            new Candidato { NumeroPartido = 45, NomeCandidato = "Deltrano", QuantidadeVotos = 0 },
            new Candidato { NumeroPartido = 99, NomeCandidato = "Branco", QuantidadeVotos = 0 },
            new Candidato { NumeroPartido = 999, NomeCandidato = "Nulo", QuantidadeVotos = 0 }
        };

        List<Eleitor> listaEleitores = new List<Eleitor>
        {
            new Eleitor { Cpf = "1", NomeEleitor = "João", VotoRealizado = false },
            new Eleitor { Cpf = "2", NomeEleitor = "Maria", VotoRealizado = false },
            new Eleitor { Cpf = "3", NomeEleitor = "Antonio", VotoRealizado = false },
            new Eleitor { Cpf = "4", NomeEleitor = "Marcos", VotoRealizado = false },
            new Eleitor { Cpf = "5", NomeEleitor = "Ana", VotoRealizado = false },
            new Eleitor { Cpf = "6", NomeEleitor = "Marcia", VotoRealizado = false },
            new Eleitor { Cpf = "7", NomeEleitor = "Marcio", VotoRealizado = false },
            new Eleitor { Cpf = "8", NomeEleitor = "Carla", VotoRealizado = false },
            new Eleitor { Cpf = "9", NomeEleitor = "Bruna", VotoRealizado = false },
            new Eleitor { Cpf = "10", NomeEleitor = "Mara", VotoRealizado = false }
        };

        while (opcao == 1 || opcao == 2 || contador < 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DIGITE A OPÇÃO DESEJADA:");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - PARA VOTAR.");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - LISTAR VOTAÇÃO.");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
            opcao = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (opcao == 1)
            {
                Console.Write("DIGITE SEU CPF PARA REALIZAR O VOTO: ");
                var CPFEleitor = Console.ReadLine();
                foreach (var itemEleitores in listaEleitores)
                {
                    if (itemEleitores.Cpf.Equals(CPFEleitor) && itemEleitores.VotoRealizado == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ELEITOR: " + itemEleitores.NomeEleitor);
                        y = 1;
                    }
                    if (itemEleitores.Cpf.Equals(CPFEleitor) && itemEleitores.VotoRealizado == false)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ELEITOR: " + itemEleitores.NomeEleitor.ToUpper());
                        contador++;
                        itemEleitores.VotoRealizado = true;
                        Console.Write("DIGITE O NUMERO DO SEU CANDIDATO: ");
                        var numeroCandidato = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (!numeroCandidato.ToString().Equals(""))
                        {
                            foreach (var itemCandidados in listaCandidatos)
                            {
                                if (itemCandidados.NumeroPartido.ToString().Equals(numeroCandidato))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("CANDIDATO: " + itemCandidados.NomeCandidato.ToUpper());
                                    Console.WriteLine("VOTAÇÃO CONCLUÍDA.");
                                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                                    itemCandidados.QuantidadeVotos = itemCandidados.QuantidadeVotos + 1;
                                    z = 1;
                                }
                            }
                            if (z == 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var itemCandidados in listaCandidatos)
                                {
                                    if (itemCandidados.NumeroPartido == 999)
                                    {
                                        itemCandidados.QuantidadeVotos = itemCandidados.QuantidadeVotos + 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            x = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (var itemCandidados in listaCandidatos)
                            {
                                if (itemCandidados.NumeroPartido == 99)
                                {
                                    itemCandidados.QuantidadeVotos = itemCandidados.QuantidadeVotos + 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (x == 0 && y == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CPF NÃO CADASTRADO");
                }
                if (y == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ELEITOR JÁ REALIZOU SEU VOTO");
                }
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
                z = 0;
            }
            else if (opcao == 2)
            {
                foreach (var item in listaCandidatos)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Candidato {0} ({1}). Votos {2}.", item.NomeCandidato, item.NumeroPartido, item.QuantidadeVotos);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OPÇÃO INVÁLIDA. TENTE NOVAMENTE.");
            }
            opcao = 0;
        }
        if (contador == 10)
        {
            ExibeResultado(listaCandidatos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito era bem isso mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Na verdade não é só o problemas do *case*, este código nem parece ser C#, tem uma quantidade de enorme de erros, apesar de funcionar na maioria dos casos. Alguns vão quebrar, outros, só são confusos, só erros conceituais, apenas tornam todo o código menos elegante e verboso demais, mas tudo que induz a erros.

Comment: @Maniero Bem visto, confesso que não olhei todo código, de primeira bati os olhos no *case* e ali fiquei(my bad). Assim que tiver um tempinho tentarei reformular a resposta analisando melhor o código.

Comment: A resposta respondeu bem o que era o foco da pergunta :) Geralmente ficaria `Cpf` e não `CPF`.

Comment: @Maniero isso do `cpf` era uma dúvida minha, que agra você respondeu rsrs